# Availability rooms depending up on dates in SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

I am developing an application is room booking. First I want to show the available rooms to the user based on his city and `fromdate` and `todate`. For this I have a table `tbl_room` with columns like `id`, `room_name`, `city`, `fromdate`, `todate` and so on.

I am trying to write a query based on `fromdate` and `todate` and `city` for showing available rooms from my table.

My query looks like this :

```
select 
    rooms, price, name, persons_capacity 
from 
    tbl_room 
where 
    city = 'xxxx' 
    and fromdate between 'yyyy-mm-dd' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

But this returns wrong results because I am not checking `todate` here.

How can I use `todate` in my query for checking availability rooms?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: Well, are you storing the **availability** of the room (as `from - to` periods), or are you storing when the room is **occupied**?

Comment: Yes,i am storing availability of the rooms in my table tbl_room in back-end. And the good question you are asked. My main problem here is can i take another table for booked rooms?Suppose if i take what is the common field between tbl_room table and my booked table?can you please tell me?i am new to this. thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select rooms,price,name,persons_capacity 
from tbl_room 
where city='xxxx' 
and fromdate <= @end and enddate >= @start
```

With @start to @end being your daterange.

Comment: why you checkd fromdate<=todate and enddate>=fromdate?i confused here thanks

Comment: I see it as: You declare a variable `@end` as your `todate` and a variable `@start` as your `fromdate`. You pass to the `@start` the `fromdate` and to `@end` your `todate`. Now you have the ranges defined. And Carra checks that the end date is not before the start date and the start date must be before the end date.

Comment: For more info on the why, you can take a ook at the comment made by  Felix Pamittan.